# what does it mean for a subset graph to be contructed from the power set of the vertices of a graph

Tags: combinatorics, elementary-set-theory, graph-theory

Definition: The subset graph of a set $S$ is constructed as follows. The vertex set is the powerset $2^S$
and two vertices $X,Y \in 2^S$ are adjacent if they have nontrivial intersection i.e. $X\cap Y$ is non-empty.

I am not sure what this even means. Conceptually, how can you construct subgraph vertices from the power set, unless this definition is meant to introduce a new idea?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's an example for $S=\{1,2,3\}$. There are $8=2^3$ vertices, labelled with all possible subsets of $\{1,2,3\}$. If two subsets have an element in common, there is an edge between the vertices with those labels. In particular this means vertex $\{\}$ is adjacent to nothing, but $\{1,2,3\}$ is adjacent to everything except $\{\}$.

(I would normally write $\varnothing$ rather than $\{\}$, but the software I made the image in couldn't cope with that!)

[image]

Comment: thank you so much, I have one follow up, I was trying to build a proof to show that the maximum clique for a graph of this type is n+1 where n is the number of vertices in S, however I am stuck on the inductive step, how would one go about solving this

Comment: @ConradG That is not correct; the maximum clique has order $2^{n-1}$.

Answer (score 1):

The intuition is as follows. Using some set $S$, we create a graph, showing the subsets of this set $S$. For every possible subset of $S$ we create a vertex in this graph, and we connect two vertices only if they have at least one element in common.

Example for the set $S = \{1,2\}$:

```
(1,2) ----- (1)
  |
  |
 (2)        ()
```